# PHP display array in Jquery UI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-autocomplete

I am new to php programming... I want to display an array in a select box. The array that I am getting calling the webservices is an associative array....called $services.

This is my text auto complete input where I want to list these:

```
<input class="sel2" id="select_service" name="Enter keywords" type="text" value="search something" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '';}" required="">
```

and here is the script before the body.

```
<script>
$(function() {
var availableTags =  <?php echo json_encode($cars); ?>;
    $( "#select_service" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
    });
});
</script>
```

Everything is working all fine. I am having a strange issue. I have defined 2 php arrays at the top and before I am displaying the autocomplete text... I am using this php code to get the array $cars

```
<?php
foreach($services as $key => $value){
//echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
$cars[] = ''.$value;
}
?>
```

What is surprising: the value is getting populated in the array... i can display them in a select box too...  can print them... but it's not appearing in the auto complete. However the auto complete code is working fine if I assign some hardcoded value in the loop. So.. the problem is ... actual values are never displaying in the auto complete.

**WHAT's MORE SURPRISING:**

The auto complete text only not displaying the value of the associated array.... even displaying the key. This is how the arrays prints.

```
Array ( [0] => Exclusive - Special Offer!!! - [Special offer] U.S.A - T-Mobile Unlock via Device Unlock App - 1-3 Days [1] => Exclusive - Special Offer!!! - [Special offer] U.S.A - T-Mobile iPhone IMEI Cleaning Service (Clean Lost/Stolen/Blocked IMEI) - 1-7 Days [2] => Exclusive - Special Offer!!! - [Special offer] U.S.A - AT&T iPhone 3G 3GS 4 4S 5 5S 5C 6 6+ (Clean) - 0-48 Hours [3] => Exclusive - Special Offer!!! - [Special offer] U.S.A - AT&T iPhone 3G 3GS 4 4S 5 5S 5C 6 6+ (Clean) - Instant [4] => Exclusive - Special Offer!!! - [Special offer] U.S.A - AT&T iPhone 6S 6S+ (Clean) - Instant [5] => Exclusive - Special Offer!!! - [Special offer] U.S.A - AT&T iPhone 3G 3GS 4 4S 5 5S 5C 6 6+ [Only Active Line IMEIs] - 1-4 Days))
```

Looks like there is some issue with the result formatting. Its displaying well in select box... but not appearing at all in auto complete.

**

> FOUND THE PROBLEM... BUT SOLUTION

**
Actually everything is working fine... here is the url http://demo.eurekageeks.com/API/GetService.php
from where I am fetching my array.... it is working for all columns but not displaying data from Name and PriceGroupName. What can be the issue.

Comment: Have you included jquey-ui.css?

Comment: Yes... so its showing the auto complete for all other values. It's only not displaying the value of the associated array.... even displaying the key.

Comment: is your html and php in the same file?

Comment: Try to make the autocomplete with ajax request. I guess you are mixing js and php code, may be this is a bad practice.

Comment: Yes.. they are in the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the link you provided. Actually there is a problem in the string format for the row with ID 1114. It contains the wrong format and hence the JQuery Autocomplete is not able to load it. Try populating the array in loop with a check

```
if($key != 1114){
$cars[] = ''.$value;
}
```

It will work just fine. You should contact the API developer or change it yourself if you are fetching it from your database.